# Displaying Images in QGIS Pop-ups from Google Maps Data

Tags: qgis

I'm working on transferring a map from Google Maps to QGIS for a web map project. The map contains numerous points, each with attributes and attached photos. While the images display fine in ArcGIS Pro, they aren't showing up in QGIS pop-ups.

I've tried importing both KMZ and GeoJSON formats, setting the image field as a URL. Despite this, the image issue persists.

How do I resolve this and achieve functional pop-up images in QGIS?